# Pandas: reverse rows with same values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame`, where rows are 'grouped' by the third column (rows in one 'group' have the same value at the third column):

```
c1 c2 c3
0   b  1
1   r  1
2   f  2
3   x  2
4   n  2
5   r  3
6   f  3
```

But the values in the second column have a wrong order. I need to reverse rows in each 'group', so `DataFrame` should look like this:

```
c1 c2 c3
0   r  1
1   b  1
2   n  2
3   x  2
4   f  2
5   f  3
6   r  3
```

Is there an effective way to transform the first `DataFrame` to the second one with `pandas`?

UPD: Updated with more clear example. The values should be exactly reversed, not just became located in the alphabetical order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(['c3','c2'])
print (df)
   c1   c2  c3
1   1    a   1
0   0    b   1
4   4   aa   2
3   3   bb   2
2   2   cc   2
6   6  xxx   3
5   5  zzz   3
```

EDIT:

You can use `groupby` and change order by `[::-1]`:

```
#more general solution, working with not unique index also
def reversing(x):
    x['c2'] = x['c2'].iloc[::-1].values
    return x

df = df.groupby('c3', sort=False)).apply(reversing)
print (df)
   c1 c2  c3
0   0  r   1
1   1  b   1
2   2  n   2
3   3  x   2
4   4  f   2
5   5  f   3
6   6  r   3

#solution working only with unique monotonic increasing index, because reset index
df['c2'] = df.groupby('c3', sort=False)['c2'].apply(lambda x: x[::-1]).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   c1 c2  c3
0   0  r   1
1   1  b   1
2   2  n   2
3   3  x   2
4   4  f   2
5   5  f   3
6   6  r   3
```

Solutions, where order of values in `c1` is changed:

You can sorting by index (has to be unique monotonic increasing).

```
df=df.reset_index().sort_values(['c3','index'],ascending=[True, False]).drop('index',axis=1)
print (df)
   c1 c2  c3
1   1  r   1
0   0  b   1
4   4  n   2
3   3  x   2
2   2  f   2
6   6  f   3
5   5  r   3
```

If column `c1` is unique monotonic increasing (0,1,2..) as default index:

```
df = df.sort_values(['c3','c1'], ascending=[True, False])
print (df)
   c1 c2  c3
1   1  r   1
0   0  b   1
4   4  n   2
3   3  x   2
2   2  f   2
6   6  f   3
5   5  r   3
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but these letters are just an example of values, sorry that I've incorrectly cited this example. In my case the values in the groups shouldn't be in alphabetical order, they should be exactly reversed. I've updated the post with more clear example.